# log4net complex type logging

Tags: c#, log4net

I want to log complex type object in c# and to use log4net for logging. What is the correct approach to do this?I use filelogappender.So I want to see my entity in log.Should I do it to use stringbuilder class and convert my entity to string or serialize it to json or is log4net has a ability to this?

```
public class Person
{
Name {get;set;}
Surname{get;set;}
}

Person personobject=new Person("MyName","MySurname");
log4net.Log.Warn(personobject);
```

Comment: Converting to JSON is the simplest way to go. You can NewtonSoft library to serialize object to JSON.

Comment: Here's a suggestion [http://www.adamtuliper.com/2012/12/logging-complete-objects-with-log4net.html](http://www.adamtuliper.com/2012/12/logging-complete-objects-with-log4net.html)

Comment: You could also override the ToString method on Person and return the objects properties in whatever format you wish to see in the log.

Comment: is  there any  outofthebox solution in log4net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm with the first comment on this if you wanna log complex objects to file or sql, the best way would be via a json conversion string using the newtonsoft library (nuget package)

you can then wrap and unwrap objects at leisure or change data on the fly (json will save you alot of time and effort.) you can also pass it back to the front end for console logging or debugging and see the object you just logged.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot log complex types, the reason is very simple:

The logging mechanism perform an hard enough work - **you have to open stream and close stream** every time you log information.

The data you stream is mostly text, there is no easy way to parse a complex object into text representation so what you see, is the 'shallow' text representation of the type: `'Object object'`.

The easy workaround is to serialize the object manually as JSON string, this way:

```
log4net.Log.Warn(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(personobject));
```

This will serialize your type as string, not as object and so, you will be able to log any complex type you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom layout that formats log message:

**StructLayout**

```
public class StructLayout : PatternLayout
{
    public override void Format(TextWriter writer, LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        LoggingEvent newLoggingEvent;
        var message = loggingEvent.MessageObject;

        if (MessageObjectBuilder.TryBuildMessageObject(message, out object newMessage))
        {
            var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            var callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType = loggingEvent.GetType().GetField("m_callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType", bindingFlags)?.GetValue(loggingEvent);
            newLoggingEvent =
                new LoggingEvent(callerStackBoundaryDeclaringType as Type,
                    loggingEvent.Repository,
                    loggingEvent.LoggerName,
                    loggingEvent.Level,
                    newMessage as SystemStringFormat,
                    loggingEvent.ExceptionObject);
        }
        else
        {
            newLoggingEvent = loggingEvent;
        }

        base.Format(writer, newLoggingEvent);
    }
}
```

**MessageObjectBuilder** - formatting the message using `Newtonsoft` :

```
 public class MessageObjectBuilder
{
    public static bool TryBuildMessageObject(object messageObject, out object newMessage)
    {
        var message = messageObject;
        var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
        object[] args = message.GetType().GetField("m_args", bindingFlags)?.GetValue(message) as object[];

        if (args == null || args.Length == 0) // not a formatted message 
        {
            newMessage = message;
            return false;
        }

        var argsAsJson = SerializeArgs(args);
        var provider = message.GetType().GetField("m_provider", bindingFlags)?.GetValue(message);
        var format = message.GetType().GetField("m_format", bindingFlags)?.GetValue(message);

        newMessage = new SystemStringFormat(provider as IFormatProvider, format as string, argsAsJson);
        return true;
    }

    private static object[] SerializeArgs(object[] args)
    {
        var newArgs = new List<string>();
        foreach (var arg in args)
        {
            newArgs.Add(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arg));
        }

        return newArgs.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And finally add this to `log4net.config` instead of your current layout:

```
    <appender name="StructLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="StructLogAppender\StrcutLog.log" />
        <layout type="Namespace.StructLayout, AssmbllyName">
            <conversionPattern value="%date{M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss.fff} - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
            <param name="LevelMax" value="ERROR" />
        </filter>
        <appendToFile value="true" />
   </appender>
```

> **Note:**

- this code using reflection so it could be a bit heavy, so its not
  recommended if performance is an issue.
- make sure to custom `Namespace` and `AssmbllyName` in `log4net.config`

Answer (score 0):

Like @micah I suggest JSON, this time with an existing solution: [log4net.Ext.Json](https://github.com/BrightOpen/log4net.Ext.Json/). Once you install the package, you can just add a `SerializedLayout` to any appender:

```
<appender...>
    <layout type='log4net.Layout.SerializedLayout, log4net.Ext.Json'>
    </layout> 
</appender>
```